# How to create view similar to honeycomb gallery?

Tags: android

Please guide me to create view similar to honeycomb gallery where user can select from the `ListView Fragment` from the right and the contents are displayed in the left side. I want to replace the content as and when item is clicked in the `ListView Fragment`.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to explain, completely and precisely, what you mean by "similar to built in contact view as in android 11 sdk".

Comment: hi commonsware, built in contact view means, sorry if I made you confused. Just go for Android 3.0 in your emulator and click on contacts app and select the existing contact or add one and after that select that again to view or edit. I want to design this kind for my app. Please suggest. Hope you understood??

Comment: "Hope you understood?" -- not really. I suggest that you look at the source code, or use Hierarchy View, or use **`uiautomatorviewer`**, and find out what you want directly.

Comment: why everytime you r voting me down??? :(. Where I can see the source code of the application which comes with sdk???

Comment: "why everytime you r voting me down?" -- I am not voting you down. "Where I can see the source code of the application which comes with sdk?" -- the same places you can see the rest of the source code. The official site is http://source.android.com, though I tend to use the mirrors at http://github.com/android for casual use. The Contacts application is at https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts.

Comment: I want to create a view similar to honey comb gallery where once user selects the contact name on right side, details should be loaded on left side. I tried to put screenshot for clear picture but not possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Looks like you want to use Master/Detail Flow. Check [this simple tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial).

Comment: hi rhoadster91. Hope you understood my question. I want to create a view similar to honey comb gallery where once user selects the contact name on right side, details should be loaded on left side. I tried to put screenshot for clear picture but not possible...

Comment: what you are looking for is Master/Detail flow. I have edited my answer.

Comment: thanks, this was the answer I was looking for.